# Pass POST data via raw HTTP

Tags: http, post

For testing purposes, I need to send some raw POST data to a page I set up on my web server. The page is working fine. I have tested sending data to via another web page as well as a C# application. However, I want to try passing raw HTTP data to it as well.

How can I do that? What client will enable me to do that? I'm looking to pass data to the page in the following form:

```
    POST /login.jsp HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.mysite.com
    User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
    Content-Length: 27
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    userid=joe&password=guessme
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want it real raw, use *telnet*. If you want something more high-level — you can use *curl*.

Comment: Unfortunately the only Linux system I have access to (my university's tux server) doesn't have curl installed. I'll try telnet. Thanks.

Comment: You can install curl on Windows: http://curl.haxx.se/download.html (scroll to the bottom of the page, or Ctrl+F, win32).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Javascript Ajax library, both jQuery and Prototype JS allow you to easily modify headers and Post data.

Comment: I'll try telnet but should that not work, I'll give the JS / Ajax library a shot